# Editing a file from command line adds strange chars to the file

Tags: command-line-interface, opensuse

I just edited a vhost file via command line

```
sudo vi /srv/.../vhost.conf
```

After saving and reopening to add something, strange chars where added to the file:

[image]

E.g.

```
AuthName "trac"n
```

was

```
AuthName "trac"
```

before.

Same with `AuthUserFile`. A *ns* was added behind it and a path.

Any ideas why this happens and how to avoid it? I also can't remove this chars.

Comment: Questions related to `vi` and so on are better on `superuser.com`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your TERM setting is wrong, editors such as vi can give a slightly scrambled display of text due to the use of inappropriate escape codes when redrawing the edited text. Does the problem disappear when you press Ctrl+L or Ctrl+R? Is the problem visible when you cat or head the file after editing?